# Javascript Skippng Code

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to create an animate using javascript and what I'm doing is showing an image, wait one second, show the second, wait, show and so on.

For some reason the first image shows, when I click to change it it jumps to the second one.

My first image looks like

```
<img src="img/board/1.png" id="spinner" alt="Click Me!" onclick="c1()"> </img>
```

And then I change the images using this.

```
function c1() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/2.png";}, 1000);
c2();
}
function c2() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/3.png";}, 1000);
c3();
}
function c3() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/4.png";}, 1000);
c4();
}
function c4() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/5.png";}, 1000);
c5();
}
function c5() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/6.png";}, 1000);
c6();
}
function c6() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/7.png";}, 1000);
c7();
}
function c7() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/8.png";}, 1000);
c8();
}
function c8() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/9.png";}, 1000);
//c9();
}
function c9() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/10.png";}, 1000);
}
```

Why is it skipping the images in between.

Comment: the images might not be cached and would take longer than 1sec to load.

Comment: You should learn about arrays (http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) and recursion. It'd make the code a lot simpler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of your functions are being executed immediately, and each of them is setting a timeout at roughly the same time. Then, 1000ms later, all the timeouts are executing. The invocation of the next function is the thing that needs to be delayed by 1000ms, not the animation itself.

Instead of this:

```
function c1() {
  setTimeout(function () { animateSomething1() }, 1000)
  c2();
}

function c2() {
  setTimeout(function () { animateSomething2() }, 1000);
  c3() ...
}
```

You need this:

```
function c1() {
  animateSomething1(); 
  setTimeout(function () { c2(); }, 1000)
}

function c2() {
  animateSomething2()
  setTimeout(function () { c3() }, 1000);
}
```

Note that your animation is ideally suited to a *single* function which just increments an index and invokes *itself*:

```
function advanceSpinner(i) {
  i = i || 1;

  if (i > 10)
    i = 1; // change this to return if you don't want to run forever

  document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/" + i + ".png";

  setTimeout(function () { advanceSpinner(i + 1) }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: How would I get this to stop or stop randomly.

Answer (score 0):

you should ad function into timeout itself rather than keeping them outside. like

```
function c8() {
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("spinner").src = "img/board/9.png";c9();}, 1000);

}
```